# Windows COM Class Name

Tags: python, windows, com

I need to create an instance of the "ICertRequest2" interface COM class using Python comtypes. How do I get the correct name to reference this?

e.g. for the ICertAdmin2 interface its called "CertificateAuthority.Admin" and I can do this:

```
certadmin = CreateObject("CertificateAuthority.Admin")
```

I need to do the same for ICertRequest2

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `CertificateAuthority.Request`

Comment: Yeah I think I worked it out thanks. Is there an easy way to list these?

Comment: They are in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.